# Calculating int next power of two

Tags: java, bitwise

Here is one of the possible solutions:

```
  public static int getNextPowerOfTwo(int value) {
    int result = value;
    result -= 1;
    result |= result >> 16;
    result |= result >> 8;
    result |= result >> 4;
    result |= result >> 2;
    result |= result >> 1;
    return result + 1;
}
```

As in your opinion is it good enough or may you suggest better one?

Comment: I don't get the reason for subtracting 1 (in the beginning) then adding 1 again in the end. Wouldn't the result be the same if one leaves that away? Just using right shift and or ... Have tried it out with a few numbers and get correct results anyway. What's the reason for the subtracting / adding. I'm dying for curiosity.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Java has [`Integer.highestOneBit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#highestOneBit(int)) that can make this a bit simpler:

```
int highestOneBit = Integer.highestOneBit(value);
if (value == highestOneBit) {
    return value;
}
return highestOneBit << 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, @janos! Integer.highestOneBit looks very simillar to my version.

Answer (score 6):

Your function is misleadingly named. It *rounds up to the nearest power of 2* rather than "getting the *next* power of 2". The difference has led @janos to suggest an answer with an off-by-one error (i.e. an off-by-a-factor-of-2-error when the input is already a power of 2).

Comment: Thanks, @200_success! I've fixed the title and the function name.

Comment: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765). I've rolled back Rev 2 → 1.

Answer (score 5):

#### Minor suggestion:

As you do not mutate the parameter `value`, you can consider marking it `final` to indicate to the user that the parameter is not changed. However, as `value` is of type `int`, which is passed by value, not by reference, you can mutate it within your method without affecting the argument, in which case, you may choose to eliminate the `result` variable.

Overall, my suggestion is either:

```
public static int getNextPowerOfTwo(final int value) {
    int result = value - 1;// note - you don't need to do this in 2 steps
    result |= result >> 16;
    result |= result >> 8;
    result |= result >> 4;
    result |= result >> 2;
    result |= result >> 1;
    return result + 1;
}
```

or,

```
public static int getNextPowerOfTwo(int value) {
    value -= 1;
    value |= value >> 16;
    value |= value >> 8;
    value |= value >> 4;
    value |= value >> 2;
    value |= value >> 1;
    return value + 1;
}
```

You have an unrolled loop, which is good for performance (especially because in Java the size of an `int` is fixed to be 32 bits). However, you could consider turning it into a loop if this performance is not required, that would reduce code duplication. Which means that you could also try:

```
public static int getNextPowerOfTwo(int value) {
    value -= 1;
    for( int shift = 16; shift > 0; shift >>= 1) {
        value |= value >> shift;
    }
    return value + 1;
}
```